# What (set of) angles are allowed between 3 detectors in the EPR experiment?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, epr-experiment

David Mermin's often cited popular example uses 60 degrees between 3 detectors which yielded  what is said to be the maximum violation. Cosine 60 squared yields 25 percent which was below the classical 33 percent(minimum) that we would expect if the experiment followed classical physics.

Question 1: can you do something arbitrarily smaller like 59 degrees  which would still be a violation but not as great? Question 2: why would 70 or 65 degrees not yield a greater violation?